# Ubuntu with integrated video card

Tags: virtualbox, intel-graphics, virtualization, google-earth

I'm planning to buy a new notebook and among the winners are some with integrated video card.

My question is how can I live on Linux with integrated card?
I want to use it for mainly programming, photo editing, watching movies and usual office stuff, no games or 3D related stuff. I'm sure I won't have any problem with these tasks. 
Also I would like to use Google Earth which is more problematic. Do you have experience with it? Any flickering?

I also would like to use some Windows in virtualized environment (virtualbox or vmware) with usual apps (no 3D or games related). Will there any problem with them?

Can I use compiz related desktop effects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a notebook (Acer Extensa 5635Z) with an integrated Intel chipset. For my experience the Intel video card always works fine with Linux. They are slow with 3D stuffs (like games) but work well with all the other applications (included Google Earth).

However a quick search with the name of your new notebook can remove all doubt. :)

Comment: I'm using an ASUS UL-20 (Intel Mobile 4) and everything works as expected, even Aero under Virtual Box. Of course gaming is out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I’m using Acer Aspire 5740G with integrated ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470.
Everything works fine, except some troubles with dual-monitor configuration, but I can even comfortably play Warcraft under wine :)

Comment: ATI Radeon card is not integrated.